# how to set foreign by post method in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

models.py

```
class Courses(models.Model):
     course_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
     course_price=models.IntegerField()

class Exam(models.Model):
     exam_name=models.CharField(max_length=101)
     course=models.ForeignKey(Courses,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='python')
     exam_time=models.DateTimeField()
```

views.py

```
def Examadd(request):
    mycourses = Courses.objects.all()
    context = {'mycourses': mycourses}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newexam = request.POST.get('examname')
        course = request.POST.get('courses')
        examtime = request.POST.get('time')
        new = Exam.objects.create(exam_name=newexam,course=course,exam_time=examtime)
        new.save()
        messages.success(request, "Course created successfully")
        return redirect('Courselist')
    return render(request,'addexam.html',context)
```

addexam.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add New Exam</h1>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label>Examname:</label>
        <input type="text" name="examname">
        <label>Course:</label>
        <select name="courses">
            {% for i in mycourses %}
            <option value={{i.id}}>{{i.course_name}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <label>Exam time and date:</label>
        <input type="text" name="examtime">
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am doing a project elearning.I want a dropdown list with courses and pass its ids to Exam table.course id is a foreign key.I want to pass the courseid to course column in Exam table.By this code I gets error as,Cannot assign "'1'": "Exam.course" must be a "Courses" instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the primary key to `course_id`, so:

```
def Examadd(request):
    mycourses = Courses.objects.all()
    context = {'mycourses': mycourses}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newexam = request.POST.get('examname')
        course = request.POST.get('courses')
        examtime = request.POST.get('time')
        new = Exam.objects.create(
            exam_name=newexam, course_id=course, exam_time=examtime
        )
        messages.success(request, "Course created successfully")
        return redirect('Courselist')
    return render(request, 'addexam.html', context)
```

I would however advise to use a `ModelForm`, this makes saving the data easier and less error-prone, but will also do proper validation: for example checking that `time` is indeed passed, and that it is formatted as a correct datetime string.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Course` instead of <s>`Courses`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Normally model fields have no prefix with the name of the model. This makes
> queries longer to read, and often want uses inheritance of (abstract) models to
> inherit fields, so using a prefix would make it less reusable. Therefore it
> might be better to rename your field <s>`course_name`</s> to `name`.

Comment: Sir Willem I think it should be `course__id=course` in `create()` method not `course_id=course`. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

At first, `create()` method doesn't require `save()` method to be called, and you can directly assign course id in the `Exam` model, so the view should be:

```py
def Examadd(request):
    mycourses = Courses.objects.all()
    context = {'mycourses': mycourses}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newexam = request.POST.get('examname')
        course = request.POST.get('courses')
        examtime = request.POST.get('time')
        new = Exam.objects.create(exam_name=newexam,course__id=course,exam_time=examtime)
        messages.success(request, "Course created successfully")
        return redirect('Courselist')
    return render(request,'addexam.html',context)
```